# RxJava : How to maintain Observable alive even after getting error in onError() or ReSubscribe the same Observable

Tags: kotlin, observable, rx-java, publishsubject

Actually I have created a RxSearch type configuration. In which I have attached an Edittext textChangeListener with the PublishSubject. Using the events to send the characters to the Observable which is being used as input for the retrofit API call.

**Problem**

Only issue I m facing is sometime I got the error from API "unexpected end of stream" inside onError() callback of observable. Once I got the error, Observable stops working. 
Observable shuts down, not able to get the characters from PublishSubject's onNext().

Look at **RxSearchObservable**

```
class RxSearchObservable {
companion object {
    fun fromView(editText: EditText): Observable<String> {
        val subject = PublishSubject.create<String>()
        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                //subject.onComplete()
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                //subject.onNext(s.toString())
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (s.isNotEmpty()) subject.onNext(s.toString())
            }
        })
        return subject
    }
}
}
```

How I subscribing and Making an Retrofit API call in side SwitchMap.

```
 RxSearchObservable.fromView(edtToolSearch)
                    .debounce(700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .retryWhen { t -> t.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
                    .switchMap { searchTerm ->
                        runOnUiThread { progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE }
                        apiManager.getSearchUnits(searchTerm)
                    }
                    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                    .subscribe({ response ->
                        Log.i("Called subscribe", ":::::::::::+++++++++++++++ GONE")
                        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val units = response.body()
                            val searchedDatasets = units?.dataset
                            if (searchedDatasets?.size!! > 0) {
                                val searchAdapter = SearchAdapter(this@MapActivity, searchedDatasets, false)
                                listSearch.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                listSearch.adapter = searchAdapter
                            } else {
                                toast("No items found !!!")
                            }
                        } else {
                            apiError = ErrorUtils.parseError(response)
                            toast(apiError.msg)
                        }
                    }, { t: Throwable? ->
                        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                        toast(t?.message.toString())
                    }))
```

Any Idea, Help, Suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A stream which errors is terminated. You can `retry()` the subscription, but this should be done conditionally only. Maybe with timeout, maybe only a few times, maybe on certain errors only.

In your case you should consider handling the error of the API call within the `switchMap`. Like this the error doesn't reach the main stream.

```
.switchMap { searchTerm ->
    runOnUiThread { progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE }
    apiManager.getSearchUnits(searchTerm)
          .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
}
```